# Name repeats in leaderboard discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, leaderboard

I've made a simple points bot for discord with a leaderboard. The problem is that if any two users have the same number of points, the name is repeated twice on the leaderboard.
I know why the problem is occurring but cannot think up of a way to stop it

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def leaderboard(doc,x=5):
    with open("playerdb.json","r") as db:
        info=json.load(db)
    leader_board={}
    total=[]
    for mem in info:
        name=int(mem)
        amount=info[str(mem)]["points"]
        leader_board[amount]=name
        total.append(amount)
    total=sorted(total,reverse=True)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Top {x} Members With Highest Points Are",color=0x7289da)
    index=1
    for points in total:
        id_=leader_board[points]
        mems=discord.utils.get(doc.guild.members,id=id_)
        name=mems.name
        embed.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}",value=f"{points}",inline=False)
        if index==x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1
    await doc.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: What is the structure of your `player.db` file? Why are the points themselves the keys?

Comment: `{"766131299944497212": {"points": 9}}` this is how my player.db looks.

Answer (score -1):

i think you don't have all the intents on?

```html
<p><strong>NOTE: Once your bot reaches 100 or more servers, this will require verification and approval. <a href="https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Read more here</a></strong></p>
```

Comment: you should probably go to [DiscordArticalIntents](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412)

Comment: i think that is the problem correct me if i am wrong

Comment: i have all the intents all in teh developer page and here too. also the bot is only in one server
the problem is occurring due to the line leader_board[amount]=name. the bot overwrites the name of the member1 with member2 as they have same points

Comment: why is the "if x" a empty statement? maybe thats the problem?

Comment: i have the same code but a little bit modified and the problem is the same but i don't know how to fix that problem hopefully you can outcome this problem!

Comment: sry abt that if ix. I was going to try something out but that's no causing the problem. I'll edit the code